# Creating Kafka Topic for Multiple Zookeepers Instances

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Reading through the Kafka [Quick Start](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart), creating a topic tied to a single Zookeeper instance (in this case localhost) is really simple using the command

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

But what if I have 3 Zookeeper servers running? Do I only need to include one of the Zookeeper urls, and will the other Zookeeper instances be notified of this new topic to help fault tolerance? Or do I need to provide all of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a ZK cluster running, it's ok to use only one ZK connection string (host:port). Topic changes will be propagated automatically to all zookeeper nodes.

If you want specify multiple ZK hosts (for failover), use comma-separated string like: host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3

Comment: what if you have a different chroot (not /). is the correct format: host1:port1,host2:port2,host3:port3/chroot or host1:port1/chroot,host2:port2/chroot,host3:port3/chroot ?

Comment: apparently the former. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1664?focusedCommentId=14155908&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14155908